# Replace customElements.define with custom logic

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

Is it possible to modify `customElements.define` and use a custom function instead?

This is what I have tried so far, but obviously this does not work because `window.customElements` is read only.

```js
const future = ["hello-world"];

let customElementsRegistry = window.customElements;
const registry = {};
registry.define = function(name, constructor, options) {
  if (future.includes(name)) {    
    customElementsRegistry.define(name, constructor, options);
  }  
}
window.customElements = registry;

window.customElements.define("hello-world", HelloWorld);
```

Is this possible or is my only option to create my own `registry` and just use that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is still configurable so you can redefine it. Though this doesn't look like a great idea for production app.

```js
const future = ["hello-world"];

let customElementsRegistry = window.customElements;
const registry = {};
registry.define = function(name, constructor, options) {
  console.log('hijacked')
  if (future.includes(name)) {
    customElementsRegistry.define(name, constructor, options);
  }
}
Object.defineProperty(window, "customElements", {
  get() {
    return registry
  }
})

window.customElements.define("hello-world", class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.innerHTML = "Hello World"
  }
});
```

```html
<hello-world>Test</hello-world>
```

Comment: Ok, cool. The idea behind this was to be able gate stuff that is not supposed to be public just yet. So this in combination with `:not(:defined) { display:none }` was at least to me an elegant way to hide small components in my app. Can you elaborate why this is a bad idea? Besides hijacking stuff in general is maybe a bad idea :)

Comment: Just all the general things about monkey-patching. Like if you change the behaviour third-party (or other developers) code might break. For example there is a bunch of other methods to implement to accurately match the interface.

Comment: I agree. Is it possible to replace just the `define` function and leave all the other intact?

Comment: I guess so, this should do the trick `Object.defineProperty(window.customElements, "define", { enumerable: false, value: function define() { /* custom logic here */}} )`